# Is there a way to embed my python script into a blog or webpage?

Tags: python, web, embed, blogs

Let me preface with saying I am a beginner and have been learning Python on my own because I got bored with bash.

I've been searching google but came up with nothing really. I just want to be able to have a user hit a button and then the script does what it does. So a way to embed my script in a box on a blog or something and you hit a button and bam! you get the output of the script.

Is there something that looks like what this site has: http://www.learnpython.org/

whereas you click a button and the script outputs to a window?

Comment: http://ideone.com or http://codepad.org

Comment: Just look in to the source of project that you showed as an example. You will figure out how it works.

Comment: Do you really want to embed it client side or are you ok with running it server side?

Comment: I'd love to be able to just put it into a blog post on blogger. Thought there would be a way but can't seem to find a way. I could easily do this if I wasn't using blogger but I'd like to solve this problem and make it work since I like solving problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are looking to run relatively simple scripts, you can try something like [Brython](http://brython.info/index_en.html), which will interpret you script using JavaScript in the browser.  If you are looking for more complex, server-side scripting, you should try looking into one of the Python web frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).

Comment: This is very helpful. I never knew there was such a thing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't directly understand Python; they only understand JavaScript for dynamic content. So, you will either want to learn JavaScript, or embed a Python interpreter like empythoned.

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you gave, a post request is sent to `learnpythonjail.appspot.com` and a json response is received which contains the output. Basically you can do the same by sending the input via post to that site and you can display the response by parsing the response json. Hope this helps. :)